# Wrapping code in a JSON object

Tags: python, json, rest

I am trying to pass a piece of code to a REST server, wrapped within a JSON object. The example code looks like this

```
data = { 'code': textwrap.dedent("""\
val NUM_SAMPLES = 100000;
val count = sc.parallelize(1 to NUM_SAMPLES).map { i =>
val x = Math.random();
val y = Math.random();
if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
}.reduce(_ + _);
println(\"Pi is roughly \" + 4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
""")
}

r = requests.post(statements_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.8.1-py2.6.egg/requests/models.py", line 805, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 338, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I checked the validity of the JSON data using JSON validator and there is an error

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
data = {        'code': t
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Any help in fixing this issue?

Comment: Which of the two calls causes the error? And what exactly are its arguments? Please extract a minimal example before asking here. In any case, it looks like you are at some point mixing Python with ECMAScript, which are two different, incompatible languages. BTW: You are still using a really old Python version, consider upgrading.

Comment: One more thing: JSON is not ECMAScript (or JavaScript), so that validator is a red herring!

Answer (score 0):

Cannot understand what's wrong. Because everything looks well, code snippet below works well on python 2.7:

```
code = textwrap.dedent("""\
val NUM_SAMPLES = 100000;
val count = sc.parallelize(1 to NUM_SAMPLES).map { i =>
val x = Math.random();
val y = Math.random();
if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
}.reduce(_ + _);
println(\"Pi is roughly \" + 4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
""")
data = { 'code': code }

r = requests.post(statements_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

If possible provide more info about that error and more claer steps to reproduce it, so i would update answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to decode the Python file instead of its output. `data =` should not be in the JSON object. It is only part of the Python code that *creates* the output. This is the JSON object you should try to validate:

Try instead this code instead:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import textwrap
import json

data = { 'code': textwrap.dedent("""\
val NUM_SAMPLES = 100000;
val count = sc.parallelize(1 to NUM_SAMPLES).map { i =>
val x = Math.random();
val y = Math.random();
if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
}.reduce(_ + _);
println(\"Pi is roughly \" + 4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
""")
}

print(json.dumps(data))
```

Save it as `emil.py` and run it with `python emil.py` on the command line. The **result** you get is a valid JSON object.

Comment: I need to use the output of json.dumps(data) as a parameter to the requests.post function. How do I do that, in this case?